# Need to add a customized horizontalistview beneath RSS Feed application

Tags: android

Can we append  component from async task to main activity (add a component beneath the main activity)

Answer (score 0):

you can use open source libraries like.. [Sephiroth Horizontal listview](https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView) 
[Meetme Horizontal listview](https://github.com/MeetMe/Android-HorizontalListView)  and there is many other libraries. you can grab than on github.
**NOTE** *Google your question before asking* and search on stackoverflow you will surely get your answer.

Comment: i have created HorizontalListVIew but unable to append it.

parent.addView(child) replaces the earlier listView(in parent layout) with the horizontalList

Comment: _Can we append component from async task to main activity (add a component beneath the main activity)_ does it mean you want to add the listitem when async task is been done.  if **yes** you can add view in onPostExecute();

Comment: main activity has listitem,
horizontallist created in async task dynamically,

How can I append this horizontallist after listitems?? Could this be done in AsyncTask

Comment: Still situation unclear.  what do you want? which library you have used?

Comment: No library used as of now.

I have an RSS Feed app in which all the news/items are contained in a list view.
Now i want one horizontal view just below the above listitem.
This Horizontal has been created dynamically and working fine(created in Async Task).

Now i want to add this dynamic horizontal list after the RSS list items.

Is it clear now ???

Comment: You have a listview already now you created another horizontal listview. and add this listview to the first?

Comment: **Suggestion** Please ask another question describing your problem with what you have tried already. like your code snippet.  and go google to grab "how to add views"

Answer (score 0):

See, **1.** if you have a listview already created. and want to add more items same as first listview items. you can add the items to the adapter.but items should be same. or so. (I am not clear)
**2.** if it is not listview (may be it is linear layout horizontal) in this you can also add views in your onPostExecute(). 
In listView how can we add view is like

```
ListView lv= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
```

assume you have set the adapter.now you want to add a view.

```
lv.addFooterView(here you can add view layout);
```

same you can do with (linear layout.)

Comment: no async task doesn't deal with UI. it does but only on onPreExecute() and onPostExecute() the doInBackground method does not run on UI. as its name implies.